# Moving a Box2D object in the direction it is facing using applyForce

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx, physics

I'm trying to apply force to a polygon physics object to move it. Whilst I can get it to move upwards easily enough, I'm trying to get it to move in the direction in which it is pointing.

Here's my current movement code -

```
private void controls(){
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)|| Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)){
        shipBody.applyAngularImpulse(-Global.ROTATIONSPEED, true);
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)|| Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)){
        shipBody.applyAngularImpulse(Global.ROTATIONSPEED, true);
    }

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)|| Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)){
        shipBody.applyLinearImpulse(Global.IMPULSE, 
                                    shipBody.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }

    System.out.println("Ship angle: " + shipBody.getAngle() * (float)(180 / Math.PI));
}
```

`Global.Impulse` is:

`public static final Vector2 IMPULSE = new Vector2(0, 25f * MetersToPixels);`

Whilst this works fine for rotating the ship, when i apply thrust, it just goes vertically up (I understand why this happens, I'm just not entirely sure how to make it move in the direction it's pointing).

Answer (score 0):

```
force.X = cos(shipBody.getAngle()));
force.Y = sin(shipBody.getAngle()));
```

Then you'll probably want to normalise that force and then multiply it by a magnitude to keep speed uniform

Comment: Sine and cosine would already yield a normalized force.  `six(x)^2 + cos(x)^2 = 1`.  They only need the magnitude.